# Adding a clickable button or text to rich:suggestionbox suggestions

Tags: richfaces

I'd like to add a button to the suggestions presented in a rich:suggestionbox (an 'x' so suggestions can be removed). Is there a way to keep from being selected?

What I've tried so far:

```
<rich:suggestionbox id="suggestionBox" for="inputText"
                            suggestionAction="#{myBean.getSugestions}"
                            var="result" fetchValue="#{result}" usingSuggestObjects="true">
                            <h:column>
                                <h:outputText value="#{result}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <a4j:outputPanel
                                    onclick="removeCommand('#{result}');Event.stop(event);">
                                    <h:outputText value="X" />
                                </a4j:outputPanel>
                            </h:column>

                        </rich:suggestionbox>
<a4j:jsFunction name="removeCommand"
    action="#{myBean.removeSuggestion}" ajaxSingle="true"
    reRender="commandInputBox">
    <a4j:actionparam name="removedCommand" />
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

The Event.stop(event) was inspired by a similar technique used by [Ilya Shaikovsky](http://relation.to/11633.lace)

I'm open to suggestions (hehe) that use completely other techniques too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technique works just fine! I had a typo that was causing a client side error that halted the onclick processing. See the edit for details.